# Code in the cloud

Tags: python, django, cloud

Is it possible to eliminate the desktop and fully code and deploy a python/django application to the cloud from within a browser?  I think Heroku makes it possible to do that with Ruby on Rails but I have not come across a Python/Django equivalent.

I think there are huge advantages of developing code in the cloud. No deployment overhead, no code versioning headaches (because the cloud will track all changes anyway), access your code from anywhere, even an iPad, if you want to make a small change to your production code. I think Heroku has already proven that this is the future of web development and browser based IDEs like Mozilla Bespin are already getting some traction.

Comment: I'm curious: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Please don't comment on your own question.  Please **update** your question with all the details and delete the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure that Heroku does that, it just a cloud space for Rails.....like phpfog (php), dotcloud (many), appengine (java, python)....

I think http://kodingen.com/ is something more like what you ask, code in the web and deploy on it.....

Haven't tried Kodingen though....

Comment: heroku does have an online ide that allows you to develop directly in the cloud

Answer (score 0):

As an updated answer to @jjchiw, [Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) provides a you with Python2 and Python3, and gives you root access to a full Ubuntu VM, so everything will work just like you expect :)

I say updated, because Kodingen turned into Koding a year ago, and is under very active development.

Let me know if you have any questions :)